# Using typedef function pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, typedef

I am trying to use function pointer, which is somewhat like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"

typedef void (*func)(int*, int*);


void func1(int *a, int*b)
{
    printf("Func1\n");
}

void func2(int *a, int*b)
{
    printf("Func2\n");
}

void func3(int *a, int*b)
{
    printf("Func3\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    func f[] = {
      func1, func2, func3
    };
    printf("Hello\n");

    for(i=0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        func fn = f[i];
        *(fn)(&i, &i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am always getting error: "void value not ignored as it ought to be"

Do not know, how to overcome this. Can anybody please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use like following :

`(*fn)(&i, &i);`

Answer (score 1):

It's either `(*fn)(&i, &i)`, or just `fn(&i,&i)`. Otherwise you're trying to dereference the result of the function call!

(Alternatively, five-star-programmers often say `(*****fn)(&i, &i)`.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you assign the return of a void function to something, which is an error.

Try this:-

```
(*fn)(&i, &i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(*fn)(&i, &i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't write `*(fn)(...)` - simple `fn(...)` is enough, no need to dereference anything. What you have means something like "Dereference the return value of fn(...)", but you obviously can't do that.